# Create springboard like main view

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, springboard

Is there some sample code, or an easy way, to implement an application with as its first view something like Springboard?

What I am looking for is just a view with basic icons which after a tab  on an icon tells the view-controller to push the view associated with the selected icon.

This in itself is not that difficult off-course (just putting images on a view), but is there an easy way to implement all the extra functionality as well (as e.g. moving the icons around (start 'vibrating' when when you push hold them), multiple pages etc.). The Facebook App seems to have this. It is probably not worth my while to write it myself, but it would be nice if there is something 'out of the box' to give the App a bit more of an iPhone feel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook uses the [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20) library for its UI. The specific view used for the SpringBoard-like interface is known as `TTLauncherView`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an endorsement (I have yet to really check this out, and I may be too entrenched in using Three20 at this point to even bother), but here is another project that implements the springboard functionality: [myLauncher on Github](https://github.com/rigoneri/myLauncher)

Answer (score 0):

You can use UICollectionView to create this

Look at this example

https://github.com/tularovbeslan/Springboard

[image]