# How to make Home screen similar to the iPhone that has similar icons and allows user to drag it, move it to one folder or delete it?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create springboard like main view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969263/create-springboard-like-main-view)

I want to create an application that is similar to the iPhone home screen. This home screen has icons that you can move and delete. Could you share with me some example code with explanation or a tutorial related to this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check this open source class: [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView/)
It works similar to a UITableView, with cell recicling, and it even supports holding to move like the iPhone springboard (homescreen).

It is not everything ready, you will need to work on that, but it is an excellent point to start from.